# DNN structured content

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We're using the free DNN platform, and trying to determine if there are any out of the box solutions for structured content. It seems everything I've found so far either refers to the paid Evoq platform (Liquid Content), or other add-ons (2sxc, OpenContent).

What we'd like to do, for example, is create a page type with pre-defined fields that an editor can fill out for patient case studies, and then have a page that loops over all of those stories to display them on the site.

We're used to working with another CMS that has robust support for this type of thing, but are pretty new to DNN, so any insight or guidance is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a module that does it. But you can always build your own module (or outsource it to a module developer). But start by looking at the [form and list module](https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.FormAndList) or a Form module like https://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/action-form-5-the-easy-complex-and-most-flexible-form-builder-for-dnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, structured content is not built-in for the community edition, though have been some talks over the years to pull it in from the paid version, Evoq.

There are a few open source solutions as the ones you pointed out that are very popular in the community. There are also a few commercial solutions. One is Evoq, though you'll find mixed feedback in the community. It's a long history to led to that.

I run DNN Sharp, one of the top vendors in the DNN space. We also have a product called [App Builder](https://www.dnnsharp.com/platform/app-builder.) that besides creating structured content on DNN it also offers a lot of application building features. Happy to connect to show you some of our use cases in healthcare.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but thanks very much for your reply.  This was helpful and gave me some additional solutions to consider, although we ultimately decided to go with 2sxc for our current project.  I'll definitely keep DNN Sharp in mind for future projects!